# unidentifiable phone component

Tags: display, hardware

I've been having a phone display problem which makes the display unreadable as seen in the images, but still usable (the top of the screen works, so it probably is a hardware problem).

[image]
[image]

I did some research and there's a component that has a weird dark spot and indent, which could be the reason for this.

[image]

My question is: what is the name of the component shown circled (the copper-colour object)? Thanks for any help.

Note: Phone is asus zenfone 2 ZE551ML, had for ~3 yrs, defect started without dropping. I don't know what site to post it on, this seemed the most appropriate.

Comment: The copper is probably just an RF shield and or a heatsink. Below it I'd wager a guess that you will find the main SoC and the modem if it is not integrated.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a component. That is a shielding for interference. 
On some phones you can just pop it off and gain access to the SoC and the other components underneath. On other phones it is soldered to the PCB and you basically can't get inside with a proper tool.

Please note that there are no user serviceable components underneath that shielding.

Answer (score 1):

That is a piece of copper foil.  It is very thin, and it covers over a large number of different components.  It's there:

- to help conduct heat away from the chips underneath, and distribute it, and/or
- to block unwanted RF interference.

You may be able to remove it and see the chips underneath or you may not, different phones are different in that respect.